# Replicate IO Exception Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking

I would like to be able to reproduce the following error:

```
  IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Any ideas on how I can do this by making a web request and then causing this error to occur?

I've tried making a web request and unplugging the network cable which didn't reproduce the error, I'm just intrigued as to how I can make it happen.

Comment: What do you want to do after you have reproduced the error. Is it to run a test?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose No, just curious really as to how some network related errors can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line will produce your exception.

The idea is:  creating a tcp listener (or Http listener) and then closing the connection without sending a valid http response.

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
Task.Run(() =>
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(8080);
    listener.Start();
    tcs.TrySetResult(null);
    while (true)
    {
        listener.AcceptTcpClient().Close();
    }
});

await tcs.Task; //wait till TcpListener is ready

Webclient wc = new Webclient();
var str = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://localhost:8080");
```